# Filter large json file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, parsing, filter

As a total beginner of programming, I am trying to filter a JSON file for my master's thesis at university. The file contains approximately 500 hashes of which 115 are the ones I am interested in.

What I want to do:

(1) Filter the file and select the hashes I am interested in

(2) For each selected hash, return only some specific keys

The format of the array with the hashes ("loans") included:

```
{"header": {
   "total":546188,
   "page":868,
   "date":"2013-04-11T10:21:24Z",
   "page_size":500},
 "loans": [{
   "id":427853,
   "name":"Peter Pan",
   ...,
   "status":"expired",
   "paid_amount":525,
   ...,
   "activity":"Construction Supplies",
   "sector":"Construction"," },
    ... ]
 }
```

Being specific, I would like to have the following:

(1) Filter out the "loans" hashes with "status":"expired"

(2) Return for each such "expired" loan certain keys only: "id", "name", "activity", ...

(3) Eventually, export all that into one file that I can analyse in Excel or with some stats software (SPSS or Stata)

What I have come up with myself so far is this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

toberead = File.read('loans_868.json')
another = JSON.parse(toberead)

read = another.select {|hash| hash['status'] == 'expired'}

puts hash
```

This is obviously totally incomplete. And I feel totally lost.
Right now, I don't know where and how to continue. Despite having googled and read through tons of articles on how to filter JSON...

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

The JSON will be parsed as a hash, 'header' is one key, 'loans' is another key.

so after your JSON.parse line, you can do

```
loans = another['loans']
```

now loans is an array of hashes, each hash representing one of your loans.
you can then do

```
expired_loans = loans.select {|loan| loan['status'] == 'expired'}
puts expired_loans
```

to get at your desired output.